# Book Recommendation on History of Spaceflight

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, engineering

I'm a CS/Engineering student at CalTech and I'm searching for a book that can help me better understand the history of spaceflight and the problems associated with getting humans to space. Since this is purely out of interest, I don't want it to be extremely intense or time-consuming (no textbooks please) but I would appreciate some technical depth. It would be even better if the focus of the book is on the engineering aspects of spaceflight.

Thank you dearly for your help

Comment: This is an awesome Goodreads list I bookmarked a few days back - [Space Race Books](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/13322.Space_Race_Books#1529409). Almost all of the great books (no textbooks) are in here at one place. It's not chronologically organized and some might not satisfy your criteria but see which one interests you and start reading.

Comment: What aspects of the history are you interested in?  For example, are you looking for a timeline of scientific/engineering achievements that made it possible?  Or of the people and the sociopolitical circumstances that enabled it to emerge?  Both are fascinating, and entire anthologies can be written of either.

Comment: Hi Paul, that’s a great question. I am actually looking for the scientific and engineering achievements that made it possible - how problems they found on the way were tackled and where the solutions arise from. In fact, even if it is about a specific space mission (a particular space shuttle or a spacestation) that would be good too. Thank you again

Comment: Heppenheimer's *Development of the Space Shuttle* is pretty good.

Comment: Might I ask what time frame are you interested in? Early developments, like Goddard and the German rocket clubs through the A-4 and Mercury? The space race--that's the classic? The Ansari X-Prize? Modern systems, like the Falcon-9, the Electron?

There are the Haynes manuals. This one, as you can see from the "Look Inside", gives a technical history from the V2 to recent times.
https://www.amazon.com/Rocket-Manual-development-technology-satellite/dp/0857333712/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=haynes+rocket+1942+onwards&qid=1591387839&s=books&sr=1-2

Comment: @Greg this is great thank you! I don’t really have a specific time period I’m interested in. This seems to cover a lot though.